# What is the relation to the pre- and post- words of an event?

Tags: antonyms

What would be the connection to words indicating the 'pre-' stage and the 'post-' stage of an event or action. E.g. 'preparation' and 'packing up' are similar in that they're sort of the mirror of each other on each side of a party, but they're not opposites of each other, they work in conjunction with each other. I can't think of many examples of what I'm trying to explain- I have an image in my mind of the relationship though.

Comment: I'm thinking *bookends* or *pairs*.

Comment: Welcome! Can you edit the question to make it a little clearer what you're looking for—a word to describe this relationship?

Comment: Like prelude/postlude, preface/afterword, predecessor/successor, prefix/suffix, preposition/postposition? You're looking for a word for such pairs? Some, like forethought/afterthought, aren't precisely pairs. Hmm...

Comment: Yeah exactly. Is there a word for those sorts of pains? introduction/conclusion could be another example.

Comment: Bookends, as @YosefBaskin suggests, is good. Begin, end; start, finish; open, close.

Comment: Perhaps *framing actions, scenes or words*

Comment: You say they're not opposites, but I think many would disagree. They're similar to "arrive" and "leave" in relationship to a party.